What exactly is multithreading? What happens in multithreading?
I was watching a lecture video on GPUs in which the lecturer says that in multithreading, registers are reserved for the warps before they are switched. Can someone explain what happens in multithreading? Thank you.
Edit: I basically want to understand the difference between switching b/w processes and switching b/w threads.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)

So, is it like obvious when someone says multithreading, that means the thread's registers are reserved?
Let us say there are processes P1 & P2 and the number of registers on the chip is 32. P1 has 8 threads, each of which use 4 registers. So does P2. Now, when there is a context switch from P1 to P2, P1's state is saved including the register values. Now, let us say we switch again from P2 to P1. How will the thread know which registers it was reserved. Is it by the relation between the thread Id and register number?

But there is no relation between thread Id and register number, I'm sorry. My question is this: what does it mean by threads are reserved and how is it done?

For answerers: this question is specifically about GPUs. "Warps" is Nvidia terminology.
